# I want to parse span innertext using simple_html_dom in php

Tags: php, html

```html
<span class="contact-seller-name">Enda</span>
```

**Now I want to echo 'Enda' inside this span tag using php**

Here's my php code

```
$url="http://website.example.com";

$html = file_get_html( $url );

$value = $html->find('span.contact-seller-name');

echo $value->innertext;
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on what you mean by echo into?

Comment: There is no variable `$post` defined in your code

Comment: Now i have corrected my code. i want to echo 'Enda' in span tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From their documentation it looks like find returns an **array** of found values matching filter parameters:

From:

> http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Code:

```
// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';
```

They also provide another example for getting a specific element:

```
$html->find('div[id=hello]', 0)->innertext = 'foo';
```

So my guess would be something like this will get you want you desire:

```
$value = $html->find('span.contact-seller-name', 0);

echo $value->innertext;
```

By adding the **0** as a parameter it returns the first found instance of that filter.

Take a look at their API here:

> http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm

It describe what the **find** method returns (an array of element objects or element object if the second parameter is defined)

Then using any of the provided methods for the element object you can get the desired text.

Full working example tested on a live site:

```
$url = "http://fleeceandthankyou.org/";

$html = file_get_html($url);

$value = $html->find('span.givecamp-header-wide', 0);

//If it can't find the element, throw an error
try
{
    echo $value->innertext;
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo "Couldn't access magic method: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Its giving me an error: "Trying to get property of non-object in D:\Programs\xampp\htdocs\personal\WebScrapping\test3.php on line 11"  on line 11 the code is: echo $value->innertext;

Comment: It looks like the DOM element you are looking for is not being found by the parser.  Either check your query tag or make sure that DOM element is there on page load. I'll edit my post above for a full working example.